# simple pattern matching in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a basic interpreter in python.
So, I am at that point where I am trying to declare whether a string entered in command prompt is a method or variable type.

So not trying any fancy stuff..

```
s="12345" #variable
s ="foo()" method
s = "foo(1234)" method
```

What is a robust way to do this (for example.. robust for whitespaces ... throw error if syntax is not proper)

My code is pretty straightforward

```
s = s.strip()

params=   s[s.find("(") + 1:s.find(")")] # find the params..
```

The above command works in case two and case three but for case 1.. it gives weird results..

Comment: What do you expect `params` to be for `'12345'`?

Comment: @Volatility: yes.. or nothing in case of 1st and 2nd case

Comment: @Volatility: basically.. these are the three cases which i am thinking to handle right now.. but i am having a lot of if elif statements..

Comment: A robust way is to write an actual parser, using something like ANTLR or pyparsing or whatever comes up under "python parser library".

Comment: @millimoose: oh .. didnt knew these.. thanks

Comment: the reason why you get the funny result in the first case is because your statement 

in case of s = 123456

s[s.find("(") + 1:s.find(")")]

produces s[-1 + 1 : -1 ]

s[0 : -1 ] so you always miss the last character

Comment: Instead of parsing the string directly, you should first break it up into tokens, i.e. strings, bracket, numbers, operators, etc. Then, parse the sequence of tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the scenarios you are asked for i think this could do the trick

have a go

```
s[ 1+s.find("(") if s.find("(") > 0 else None : -1 if s.find(")") > 0 else None]
```

edit:
making a bit neater as suggested by Paul:

```
s[ 1+s.find("(") if '(' in s else None : -1 if ')' in s  else None]
```

Comment: I think this would be clearer if it weren't crammed on to one line.

Comment: I think this would also be clearer if you used the more up-to-date idiom of `if '(' in s` instead of `if s.find('(') > 0`.